# Are all biregular graphs connected?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

a simple question that I can't really seem to prove.
I have a biregular graph (as in a graph with n vertices and each vertex has a degree of 'd') and it is also bipartite. I'd like to prove it is connected, as in there is a path between every two vertices.

Any advice?

Comment: In this way, this argument is false. Are you sure there is no bound on $d$?

Comment: Well I think given Brian's answer I'm satisfied. The actual problem I'm trying to prove is that an Adjacency matrix of a d-regular graph has -d as an eigenvalue iff it contains a bipartite connected component.
I was able to show that for an eigenvector 'u' that belongs to the value -d that if I take the indices where u is positive as one side and the negative values for the other side that component is bipartite but I'd like to also show it must be connected

Comment: Alright, no problem then. Good luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn’t necessarily true:

```
                    *       *
                    |       |
                    *       *
```